# How can I access the result of an asynchronous task in asyncio python using the task name?

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio

I have been wanting to calculate the progress of an asynchronous task. So, I have created another async function "progress" that I am awaiting from the for loop inside the original function after every `n` iterations. Now, I created an async django view where I want to access the result of the task(progress function) with the name I set, and return that as HttpResponse.

My Django View

```
async def get_progress(request, job_id):
    task = get_the_task(name=job_id)
    return task.result
```

Working Function of which I want to calculate the progress

```
async def working_function(request, job_id):
    for i in range(x):
        after_every_n_iterations:
            await asyncio.create_task(progress(i, x), name=job_id)
```

This is my progress function

```
async def progress(work_till_done, total_work):
    return work_till_done/total_work*100
```

I don't know where to go from here. Kindly help me.

Comment: What is the reason for creating a task if you awaiting it?

Comment: Yeah you are right i could simply use a function there.

Comment: I meant `asyncio.create_task` loses its meaning when you `await`ing it

Comment: I need that function call to be finished there and then so that the status/progress of the task can be updated. But can you help me with the question?

Comment: What do you exactly want, to see the progress of your running iteration or make this code work?

Comment: Django's view can only return a result but not yield so you have to wait until the iteration ends then return the result. How do you plan to show that progress?

Comment: To see the progress of my running iteration after every n iterations, and I wrote the code for understanding purposes.

Comment: I want to show a progress bar for this program, do you have any ideas how can I achieve this?

Comment: Yes, let me prepare my answer

Answer (score 0):

For using `async` functions in Django you have to use [`ASGI`](https://asgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#how-does-asgi-work) but with `yield` you can still use `WSGI`.

I would use `yield` for solving this.

```
def working_function(job_id):
    for i in range(x):
        yield f"<div>{job_id} has been done ({(i/x)*100})%</div><br/>"
```

And your View should look like

```
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse

def get_progress(request, job_id):
    return StreamingHttpResponse(working_function(job_id))
```